# Problema conexión SQL

Tags: sql

Me ha sucedido que repentinamente perdí el acceso al programa de contabilidad Contpaq, que requiere conexión a SQL en servidor, recientemente se actualizo el windows 10 y se perdió la conexión con las terminales, se modifico el usuario de windows y se restauro como estaba, ahora la contraseña le fue modificada y acudo a ustedes para saber alguna solución que me sea de ayuda.

Intente cambiar contraseña por CMD:

[image: CMD]

y agregar un nuevo usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no funcionó.

Comment: Buenas tardes.. Tu pregunta no es sobre programacion ni nada referido a eso, si no mas bien sobre un problema tecnico en tu SQL server. Creo que tendras mas suerte si preguntas al soporte tecnico de ese sistema en particular. Por lo pronto deberias probar si luego de la migracion sigue aceptando conexiones remotas tu windows

Comment: En la practica no acepta conexiones desde las terminales, pero en configuración de superficies para servicios y conexiones esta habilitado las conexiones locales y remotas en usar solo TCP/IP, ¿A que se refiere con migración? ¿A las actualizaciones recientes?

Comment: tal vez lo este bloqueando windows 10?

Comment: El cortafuegos esta deshabilitado, hace poco cambie de usuario de windows por error pero inicie sesión en el mismo de antes, desconozco si con eso se cambio alguna configuración como permisos o rutas, o solo haya sido problema de las actualizaciones obligatorias al apagar y encender el equipo.

Comment: ¿Tu sabes si es posible hacer una restauración del equipo desde un punto anterior? ¿Y si es así desde cuanto tiempo se podría hacer? ¿Eso no quitaría configuraciones?

Comment: En este sitio se admiten preguntas sobre [administración y uso avanzado de bases de datos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/167/301) y sobre [gestión de servidores y redes de ordenadores](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/166/301). Por favor, no voten para cerrar por no relacionado.

Comment: Las versiones de SQL Server anteriores a 2012 no son compatibles con Windows 10, puede ser ese el problema: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/2681562/using-sql-server-in-windows-8-and-later-versions-of-windows-operating

Answer (score 1):

1. Busca en el menú inicio dentro del grupo de programas del SQL Server
   que tengas instalado el programa **SQL Server Configuration
   Manager**
2. En el panel de la izquierda selecciona **Configuración de Red de SQL
   Server XXXX**
3. En el panel de la derecha haz doble click en **Protocolos de -
   instancia de SQL Server que quieras modificar-"**
4. Ahora, en el panel de la derecha comprueba que TCP/IP está
   habilitado. En caso contrario botón derecho encima de TCP/IP y
   selecciona Habilitar

En el panel de la izquierda, deberías tener Configuración de SQL Native Client (32 bits) y otro sin lo de 32 bits (es el de 64 bits en caso que tengas un SQL Server de 64 bits).

En cada uno de ellos, tienes que tener una sección de **Protocolos de Cliente**, dentro de la cual deberías tener el **TCP/IP habilitado** también, y si pinchas dos veces en TCP/IP en la ventana que te saldrá deberías tener el **puerto 1433** (o el que desees) indicado en **Puerto Predeterminado**

Esto que te he puesto es para el SQL Server 2005.

En los más modernos todo se hace desde **Configuración de Red de SQL Server XXXX**

En caso que tengas múltiples IPs en el servidor te saldrá una pestaña en la ventana de propiedades donde para cada IP puedes establecer una configuración diferente. Para poner en todas las IPs la misma configuración tienes que ponerlo en la sección **IPAll**.

En los SQL Server más modernos también hay un campo nuevo llamado **Puertos Dinámicos TCP** que deberías de dejar vacío o a 0.